# Query working in HQL but not when asking it to display on JSF

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2

So i have tried the query in HQL with a simple

```
SELECT fa.actor FROM FilmActor fa WHERE fa.film.filmId = 1
```

I am using the DAO concept by the way so this line of code is the FilmActorDaoImpl But when I try to put it into a list using a session.create query it doesn't turn it into a list. So basically the site is when you click on a link you can go to its showcase page featuring all the description, title of the movie. It doesn't work when you call the list in the jsf page because of a lazy initialization error so I decided to query it in a DAOImpl with its own DAO

```
    public List<Actor> listOfActorsFromFilm(short filmId) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<Actor> result = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        session = factory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        result = session
                .createQuery(
                        "SELECT fa.actor FROM FilmActor fa WHERE fa.film.filmId = : filmId")
                .setEntity("filmId", filmId).list();
        tx.commit();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is the bean for that showcase. Everything is going through except the filmActors. So all of the description, title is being displayed

```
@ManagedBean(name = "filmShowcase")
@SessionScoped
public class FilmShowcaseBean{

    @ManagedProperty("#{filmActorDao}")
    private FilmActorDao filmActDao;

    private Film film;
    private List<Actor> filmActors;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if(film != null){

              filmActors = filmActDao.listOfActorsFromFilm(film.getFilmId());
              System.out.println(filmActors.size());
        }else{



        }
    }

    public Film getFilm() {
        return film;
    }

    public void setFilm(Film film) {
        this.film = film;
    }

    public List<Actor> getFilmActors() {
        return filmActors;
    }

    public void setFilmActors(List<Actor> filmActors) {
        this.filmActors = filmActors;
    }

    public FilmActorDao getFilmActDao() {
        return filmActDao;
    }

    public void setFilmActDao(FilmActorDao filmActDao) {
        this.filmActDao = filmActDao;
    }




}
```

Comment: _" But when I try to put it into a list using a session.create query it doesn't turn it into a list. "_: What **does** it turn into?

Comment: The HQL given is not meant to fetch a list of fully qualified entities. It is instead meant to fetch a list of tuples (part of an entity). The query implicitly returns a `List<Object[]>` (not `List<Actor>`). You should get a `java.lang.ClassCastException`, if the list is attempted using a loop such as `for(Actor actor : filmActors) {...}`. If you, nevertheless, want the HQL to return a `List<Actor>`, you need to change it like so, `SELECT fa FROM FilmActor fa WHERE fa.film.filmId = :filmId`. Besides, a session scoped managed bean, in this case, appears to be completely unnecessary.

Comment: I found the answer. Apparently I had to use setShort instead of setEntity for some reason. And also using it in init is apparently wrong. I put the method at setFilm and it worked. Although not quite sure how it is calling setFilm on it's own. Thank you Tiny for your answer btw that cleared up some things but i'm still not sure how the behind the scenes of it is working.